# script to know application pool,bindings

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5

Do we have any powershell command or powershell script to get the website details as website name, application pools associated to,.Net version,bindings mapped to website.

do we have a single line command or any script where we can get the details??

For Example:

```
Name            ApplicationPool   .NetVersion     Bindings                 
Defaultwebsite  DefaultApppool    v4.001234       www.hello.com
```

Comment: Didn't try anything am pretty novice to powershell

Comment: Well, here at SF we expect you to have at done some research and at least tried to solve the problem yourself. You'd then come to us with specific issues/errors with which we might be able to provide some guidance. In short, we're not a script writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use powershell module WebAdministration, to view commandlets:

```
(Get-Module WebAdministration).ExportedCmdlets
```

For example, command to get web-sites:

```
Get-Website
```

To get names of AppPools:

```
(Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools\).Name
```

More information: https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee790599.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the response am able to get the results with the above commands too, now am trying to merge to get the results in a table format.

Comment: Try to transfer your result through the pipeline to **Format-Table** command.